# How do I find the corners of a plane in 3d space if I know three points

Tags: matrix, 3d, scenekit

Apologies in advance for my feeble maths.

I'm trying to be able to find the corners of a plane in space based on the equation of that plane. Here's what I know. I know three points on the plane and I know where they fall in the 2d coordinate space of the plane (x,y) and where they are in 3d space. I know the width and height of the plane and I can now calculate the equation of the plane. The plane sits on the inside of a large sphere that surrounds the origin so, in theory, it should more or less face where the camera is (though in my diagram it doesn't face the origin as it's just for illustrative purposes)

But it's not clear to me how I can use that to figure out another point. One thought I had was to find the transform that moves the plane parallel to the xy axis and rotate it round one of the points (so it stays in the same place), find the position of the new point, and then rotate it by the inverse of that transform. But it's not clear to me how I would find that transform matrix or how to use it. Could I do this using the normal and vector maths? I understand what normals are, but I'm fuzzy about how to use them.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what is meant by "The plane sits on the inside of a large sphere that surrounds the origin" ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Perhaps it would help if I explain the scenario. Surrounding the camera and the origin of the scene is a large sphere with a star map of the heavens. I am using the coordinates of three stars in a constellation to position an image of that constellation. The image will be facing the camera and just on the inside of the sphere. By knowing the position in  3d space of three of the stars and the position of those stars in the plane I'm trying to place the vertices of the plane so it matches the stars on the inside texture of the sphere.